# how can i plot a formula with different parameters? in R

Tags: r, plot, formula

I cama across a video that shows how a transformation parameters, specifically in the reach function for diminishing returns, affect the outcomes.

the formula for the function is:

[image]

and the plot should look something like this:

[image]

How can i recreate this plot in R ?

I started writing a funtion:

```
reach <- function(MU){
  1-e^{MU * x * t}/ 1+e^{MU * x * t}/
}

mu <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
for(i in seq_along(mu)) {
  curve(weibull(.5, mu[i], x), from=0, to=2, add=i!=1, col=col[i], ylim=c(0,50), main="alpha=.5")
}
```

I do not know how to translate the formula into R code. Also i do not have any x,m or t. Are there simulated or how i am supposed to deal with that? Any tips?

Comment: Does my update answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help get you started?

```
reachFun <- function(mu, x, t) {
  (1L - exp(-mu * x * t)) / (1L + exp(-mu * x * t))
}

mu <- seq(1L, 7L, 2L)
t <- 1L
colours <- c("blue", "orange", "green", "red")

invisible(
  x = lapply(
    X = seq_along(mu), 
    FUN = \(i) curve(
      expr = reachFun(mu = mu[[i]], x = x, t = t), 
      from = 0L, to = 1.4, 
      col = colours[[i]], 
      ylim = c(0L:1L), 
      add = TRUE, 
      xlab = as.expression(bquote(bold("Marketing ..."))), 
      ylab = as.expression(bquote(bold("C... A....")))
      )
    )
)
legend("topleft", 
       legend = paste("mu =", mu), 
       col = colours, lty = 1L)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank! Any idea why there is such a big difference between how the plots look?